# Why doesn't `every edge` work with `--`

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, edge

In TikZ, why doesn't `every edge` work with `--`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[every edge/.style={draw=red}]
        \draw (0,1) -- (1,1);
        \draw (0,0) edge (1,0);     
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: edges]

Is there a different `every` key I should be using?

Comment: Use `every path/.style={draw=red}`.

Comment: Ack! I thought I had tried that and it didn't work either. It works, though. Would you write this as an answer?

Comment: Also, does `--` technically not create an `edge`, but something else?

Comment: No, `--` does not start an edge. It is more the other way around: an `edge` inserts a (sort of) independent path in a given path construction. "Sort of" means that it still inherits the keys of the ambient path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want both lines to become red, use the `every path` key.

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={draw=red}]
    \draw (0,1) -- (1,1);
    \draw (0,0) edge (1,0);     
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An `edge` is different from a path. For instance, it does not move to the end point of the edge.

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (0.5,1.5);
    \draw (0,0) edge (1,0) edge (0.5,0.5);     
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also the line joins for the edge are not taken car of.